# Elasticsearch is taking more time while doing bulk requests

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I have ES cluster of 16 nodes. The total data size in the cluster has 750GB. I used replication factor as 1. So the data size is 1.5TB.

Each node is having the following specification:

500GB SSD raid 1
64GB ram
8 cores CPU
Head size is 30G
I am facing the slowness issues in the bulk calls. In the logs, we found the queue size is full.

1) I updated the 3 nodes as a master and co-ordinating nodes, then also we got the same errors in the log files. How to solve these errors and How to increase the query performance?

2). Is there any way to find out the max limit of our existing cluster capacity?

Comment: How large are the bulk requests?  Might want to split them up and find an optimized size per request.

Comment: Each request is having 500 queries. If we split them by 100. It may take more time to get the response of 200k tokens.

Comment: What is the actual *size* of the requests (in MB)?  Tuning the size can increase performance and reduce time. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_using_and_sizing_bulk_requests